# How do I get all 3 characters together for the "Three man army" trophy?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Over the course of my entire game I have been trying to phone each of the protagonists in order to get this trophy. Each time I successfully 'Hang Out' with one of the characters the other one is always unreachable (busy tone on their cell) or not interested.

What is the easiest way to get all three characters together in order to get this trophy/achievement?

Secondly, there are obviously points in the story where this is not possible due to certain characters being otherwise occupied. Is there a best or easiest time to get the characters together?

Specifically:(End game spoiler)

> I want to know if it is still possible to get this trophy in post game. I choose option C: Deathwish which resulted in all three characters surviving (and becoming friends again) but I still can't get them all together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How to get three characters together**

Before you can do this you must complete the story mission "Friends Reunited" to be able to have all 3 characters hang out together. After that you can call the other two characters via the "Contacts" icon in the in-game mobile phone.

Make sure you **call both** other characters immediately **before picking them up**, because if you pick one up first before you call the other then you will get a "busy" tone on your phone.

**Being able to get "Three man army" trophy even at final mission or after**

"[MISSABLE] This trophy can be missed if you have not unlocked it by the time you get to the final mission. Make sure you choose "**Option C**" when offered the choice, after which this trophy is **no longer missable**."

According to the following link and the above text you should still be able to obtain the trophy.

http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/grand-theft-auto-v/trophy/68567-Three-Man-Army-.html

If you didn't get the trophy before the final mission, and choose option A or B, then you're not longer able to do it.

Comment: Just emphasising the fact that you have to call both before picking either up, that stumped me for a long time!

Comment: This is in line with the information I have found already but it doesn't work for me. I have tried it several times with different combinations of characters.

Comment: Can you explain how this is missable?  Fair enough, choosing option C at the final mission will change this, but that description suggests that you can make it missable *before* you get to the final mission : `This trophy can be missed if you have not unlocked it by the time you get to the final mission`

Comment: @Archer If you didn't get the trophy before the final mission, and choose option A or B, then you're not longer able to do it.

Comment: @ykb Thank you - makes perfect sense now it's explained :)

Comment: I wonder if this can achieve with a boat / flight. Also, can hangout with other two people also count? haven't tried yet.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to phone both before picking them up, because at one point the call got through, and Franklin said "hey Mike, wanna hang out with me and Trevor?" or something to that degree, so the dialogue has been written for it. In the dialogue, Michael declines, and then every subsequent time I tried, it would say "busy". Also, it seems you can't invite both if the character says "stay where you are and I'll come to you", for example if you're near an activity.

Comment: Update: I was playing a save where I had completed Friends Reunited, but not all missions, and it wouldn't let the 3 be together. But then I tried with my 100% mission game, and it allows it. So I guess there has to no animosity for them to hang out. Even with them all next to each other, they wouldn't hang out together.

Answer (score 2):

Play up to the mission where you steal Madrazo's wife. Then, Trevor and Michael will be together so go as Franklin and travel to Sandy Shores. Just remember this just gets you all together not able to do activities.

Answer (score 0):

I personally got the 3 characters together I'm the same general vicinity (I.e. beachfront near the Ferris wheel all around 30 ft apart) then had one character meet up with another by indirect means. They usually ask to hang. after getting two together I bring the two to the third guy. discovered this on my own. Hope it helps.