# Three Man Army Achievement problems

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I already checked [the other question about it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136532/how-do-i-get-all-3-characters-together-for-the-three-man-army-trophy) ([How do I get all 3 characters together for the "Three man army" trophy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136532/how-do-i-get-all-3-characters-together-for-the-three-man-army-trophy)) but I still can't make it. I've done the final mission and **chose option C**...

> ...(not to kill Trevor and Michael).

But now if I'm with Trevor and call Michael to hangout he accepts it, but **before I pick him up I call** Franklin and he's busy or not answering. It's always happening with every other combinations. Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: @kotekzot yes, actually is the first thing I said in the question. I checked that one but still having problems.

Comment: I got the achievement 2 weeks ago trick is if you're playing as Michael call Trevor/Franklin first once you are very close to picking them up call the other person. it will give you enough time to get to the second character

Comment: @Dredd perfect, I'll check after work and let you know if it works so you can put it like an answer.

Comment: I'm surprised that people are having difficulty with this.  As Michael I called Franklin and arranged to pick him up and then immediately called Trevor and arranged to pick him up as well.  This works for me every time - it's literally never failed :s